# How to do JavaScript Library Dependency Injection in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I include JavaScript libraries on a controller basis using Angular?

For example, I'm using `morris.js` and `ckeditor` in this project which require nearly 1MB (dev versions) of resources even though they are only used on two pages.

It's obviously a waste to include these within the entire single page application by referencing them in the `index.html` file.

Is there a way to use Angular Dependency Injection to include these in a controller? I'm guessing using a service or a directive but I'm not sure how those components would look in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using require.js to load these modules in your SPA based on when you need them.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. After reading more about require.js and Angular that seems to be the best approach.

Comment: Glad I could help, Brandon. Good luck with your application.