# Inject pure javascript in Service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add some data structures (linkedList, Graph) implemented in pure js and use them in a Service.
I'm sure there is a better way than statically include libraries in your html page and attach them to the window object.
what's is the most clean way to 'inject' pure code in a Service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do JavaScript Library Dependency Injection in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036758/how-to-do-javascript-library-dependency-injection-in-angular)

Comment: You can still have your 'pure JavaScript' library turned into a Service, and just inject it into your other service the angular way.